# ps throws error /proc/PID: No such file or directory

Tags: ps

Can you please tell me why "ps auxw" returned me the following error ?

/proc/15067: No such file or directory

The following is the process which was running at that time and was listed by PS.

ftpib    15067  0.0  0.0   3724   344 ?        S    22:40   0:00 bin/qmail-inject

What are possible causes for such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you've simply encountered a race condition, in which the process exits (a) after ps gets the list of process ids but (b) before it actually reads the files in `/proc`.  Linux -- and I suspect this is true for other unix-like operating systems -- does not provide an atomic mechanism for obtaining information about running processes.

Comment: Interestingly, the process was listed by the ps output, but didn't exist in /proc...

Comment: I suspect it *did* exist in /proc, but went away while ps was running.  I haven't looked at the code, but it's possible ps performs multiple reads of the /proc files for a process -- thus succeeding once and getting some data but failing a second time.

Comment: It listed the process as you can see in my above post. Do you think that while PS was reading more information from proc the process ended ?

Comment: I got your answer, Sorry i didn't refresh the page.